# python - Error calculating length in LineString objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, geopandas, shapely, multilinestring

Currently dealing with two errors while programming the code shown below, I was wondering if anybody could help me or give some tips to solve them, thank you.

1) When trying to assign multiple `LineString` objects to a `MultiLineString` object I encountered difficulties. The idea is to create a `name` depending on the feeder (`fdr`) and use it as a variable in the `MultiLineString`object. Different methods were tried (e.g. globals()[], list comprehension,..), but generate errors or like in the code below gives an `AssertionError`. The problem is that `namen` produces string objects **'l_6_1', 'l_6_2', ..** while variables **l_6_1, l_6_2, ..** are required. (SOLVED)

2) My second question is related to calculating lengths, where the `gdf` are read with `espg:4326`, I applied a conversion in the class object (which changes the LineString object! --this has been checked), meanwhile the result from `print(lengte)` isn't affected.. Any ideas where my mistakes are?

```
class Lines:
    def __init__(self, fdr, node, gdf):

        j= 1
        lines= {}
        gdf= gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})

        for i, k in zip(node[0::2], node[1::2]):
            name= 'l_'+str(fdr)+'_'+str(j)
            lines[name]= LineString([gdf.loc[i][['X', 'Y']], gdf.loc[k][['X', 'Y']]])
            lengte= lines[name].length 
            print(lengte)
            j= j+1

        lines= pd.Series(lines)
        s= lines.values

        f= geometry.MultiLineString([l_6_0]+ list(s))
        self.f = ops.linemerge(f)
```

Further I append this to a map and save (& export) since I work with Spyder.

```
x= Lines(6, nodes_6, gdf6)  
folium.GeoJson(x.f).add_to(m)
m.save(os.path.join(dest, "grid.html"))
```

Comment: Is `l_6_0` a LineString ? In that cases the items in your namen list should be LineStrings as well .. So maybe if you did something like  : 
`f = geometry.MultiLineString([l_6_0] +  lines.values())`

Comment: @LuisBlanche Indeed it is a `LineString` and I did try this as well, but gave me a `TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`. Maybe important to note: when using `lines['l_6_1'], lines['l_6_2'], ..., lines['l_6_X']` instead of `namen`, no error occurs and the map displays all the lines.

Comment: My mistake : try `f = geometry.MultiLineString([l_6_0] + list(lines.values())`   then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@LuisBlanche while checking for the properties of `values()` I noticed this was applicable for dataframes and **not** dictionaries. The answer for the first problem is solved by applying `s= lines.values` and further slice it as a list into the `MultiLineString`.

```
class Lines:
    def __init__(self, fdr, node, gdf):

        j= 1
        lines= {}
        gdf= gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3857'})
        for i, k in zip(node[0::2], node[1::2]):
            name= 'l_'+str(fdr)+'_'+str(j)
            lines[name]= LineString([gdf.loc[i][['X', 'Y']], gdf.loc[k][['X', 'Y']]])
            lengte= lines[name].length 
            print(lengte)
            j= j+1

        lines= pd.Series(lines)
        s= lines.values

        f= geometry.MultiLineString([l_6_0]+ list(s))
        self.f = ops.linemerge(f)
```